# FFT in Excel -- How to Get Second and Third Harmonic?

Tags: excel, fft

I have experimental data consisting of 1253 points of one period of a sine wave (with an offset) with second and third harmonic and am trying to apply the FFT feature of Excel. Because FFT needs 2^n data points I had to truncate the initial data set by first deleting every 6th row and then deleting every 52nd row which left me with 1023 points so I just doubled the last one to get the needed 1024 data points. Thus, I lost 229 points not knowing what else to do (padding with zeros doesn't seem plausible because that's adding a step function which is even more undesirable as a modification of the original data set). Now, when I do the FFT on the thus truncated data set I see a peak at 0Hz which is due to the offset and a peak at the fundamental frequency. How do I get the peaks of the second and third harmonic and is there a way, say by using a macro, to carry out a Fourier transformation, not FFT, on all the experimentally obtained 1253 points? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to delete any data points then they should be at the start and/or end of your data (i.e. don't try and manually decimate the data - just truncate it). It's probably better though to just pad your data with additional zeroes to the next power of 2 (2048).

Next you need to apply a [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) e.g. Hann, in order to minimise [spectral leakage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage). This will reduce the effect of any discontinuity at the start/end of the data. (Note that for zero padded data the window function is applied prior to padding.)

After the FFT you need to calculate the magnitude of the first N/2 complex output bins (`sqrt(real*real+imag*imag`)).

If the fundamental peak is at bin `N`, then the second and third harmonics will be at bins `2*N` and `3*N`.

Comment: That is done through =IMABS(D1). How are the second and third harmonic obtained, however? Also, as I said, adding a step function (by padding with zeros) seems to modify the initial data set more than removing points from it.

Comment: You weren't applying a window function previously - this will remove the effect of a discontinuity at the start/end of your data.

Comment: This part I don't get. What discontinuity? The moduli of what I get from FFT Excel span from 0Hz to the fundamental frequency continuously and there's nothing beyond it. Shouldn't there be a peak at twice the fundamental frequency, three times etc.? By the way, I see a small peak at half the fundamental frequency. Negligible, compared to the peak at 0Hz and that at the fundamental frequency. What should that be?

Comment: The step function will damage your analysis less than the jitter from decimating it.  You don't need a window function, since there is no interference whoose "leakage" you need to worry about.  Removing the average offset before doing the fft will get rid of peak around bin 0.

Comment: Thanks, @hotpaw2. It appears that my main concern should be the folding frequency. If I pad with zeros my data up to 2048 points then the folding frequency will be in the 1025th bin. Thus if my sampling rate is 1e9 I will be able to see meaningful peaks only up to 500kHz which is less than even the fundamental frequency let alone second and third harmonics. Therefore, I should conclude that my sampling rate is too low for harmonics to be seen. Am I right?

Comment: The length of the FFT does not change the "folding" frequency.  It remains Fs/2.

Comment: I understand that but the chronic problem still remains -- my sampling rate is too low to even see the fundamental, not to speak about the harmonics, right?

Comment: So long as your sample rate satisfies the Nyquist criterion then you should be able to see all the peaks in your spectrum. If Fs is 1E9 Hz then you will be able to identify components from 0 to 5E8 Hz but with a 2048 point FFT the resolution of each FFT bin will only be around 2.5E5 Hz.

Comment: Re the aforementioned discontinuity - this arises due to the fact that your input data is considered to be periodic - the data wraps around from the last sample to the first - if there is a significant step change between the first and last sample then you will see this as smearing of your peaks and it will tend to make the smeared DC component mask information in the low frequency bins. Anyway, I suggest you try with/without a window function and see how the spectrum looks in each case.

Comment: @Paul R, could you please explain this a little more. Say you have an 800kHz sine wave. It can be fully characterized by points 1/(2*800kHz)=6.25e-7s apart. Therefore, points 1e-9s apart will characterize it even better. Nevertheless, as far as I understand the Excel FFT will give meaningful peaks only up to 500kHz for that 1e-9s resolution. How then should I be able to see all the peaks in my spectrum? Sorry, I was typing while you were posting your response.

Comment: To put it in general terms: firstly for sample rate Fs, Nyquist is Fs/2 - all your information must be within a bandwith of Fs / 2. As for FFT resolution, each output bin has a *width*, or resolution of Fs / N, where N is the number of points in the FFT (i.e the number of input samples). So for Fs = 1e9 Hz = 1 GHz and N = 2048, Nyquist = 5e8 Hz = 500 MHz and bin width = 1e9 / 2048  = 488 kHz. So bin 0 = DC (0 Hz), bin 1 = 488 kHz, bin 2 = 976 kHz, bin 3 = 1.46 MHz, etc.

Comment: How about if the signal to be analyzed is 800kHz sine wave, Fs is 1e9Hz and N = 2048, at what frequency will be the last bin in the FFT?

Comment: @Paul R, thanks a lot, now I got it. One more thing. I see a difference between the FFT spectrum padded with zeros and the spectrum of the truncated data. The truncated seems more realistic because the higher harmonics (higher than second) appear to be orders of magnitude lower than the fundamental.

Comment: Without a window function the magnitude of the peaks can be somewhat unpredictable. It might be a good idea if you could post your data somewhere and put a new question on DSP.stackexchange.com and let people try different methods of generating power spectra from your data. Incidentally, what is the source of the data,, if you don't mind me asking ?

Comment: Data come from a storage oscilloscope. They are saved to a flash drive and then crunched using Excel. Do you know if stackexchange.com has a way to upload a file? Where do people usually upload their files to be discussed here? Your suggestion to open a new question is very good.

Comment: If it's only 1253 data points then you could probably get away with including the data at the end of your question - otherwise if your ISP gives you any web space then just put it there and link to it.